# unable to get jQuery .submit() to fire

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I cannot get jQuery .submit() to fire on my form. The alert below pops successfully if I move it to $(document).ready(), but trying to get it to fire on submit is just not working.

Using the following script in my BODY

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function($) {
    $('mainForm').submit(function() {
      alert("hello");
    });
  });
</script>
```

And form element below

```
<form id="mainForm" class="form-horizontal" method="POST">
<legend>Retrieve Your Documents</legend>
<fieldset>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="id">Request ID</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="requestid" name="requestid" type="text" placeholder="DOC123456-12345678901234" class="form-control input-md" required="">  
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Password input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="lastfour">Last Four of SSN</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input id="lastfour" name="lastfour" type="password" placeholder="1234" class="form-control input-md" required="">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Button -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="button"></label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="submit" id="button" name="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Retrieve Documents">
  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: `$('#mainForm')`: You're missing the `#`

Comment: This did the trick, but I had actually already tried that before and it wasn't working. However, I was explicitly using HTML4 as the DOCTYPE. When I switched to HTML5 it worked as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As haim770 said, `mainForm` is the id of your form hence you need to prefix it with a `#` like this:

```
$('#mainForm').submit(function() { 
    alert("hello"); 
});
```